# Error: Cannot find module "fibers/future" in docker container

Tags: docker, meteor

A Meteor project runs OK on the local machine and it is used to work OK on the EC2 docker container, but for some reason, it is now failing, here is the what I found from the EC2:

```js
 docker logs be664c9bce8a
/opt/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:392
}).run();
   ^

Error: Cannot find module "fibers/future"
    at Object.require (/opt/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:232:24)
    at packages/meteor.js:93:20
    at packages/meteor.js:263:4
    at packages/meteor.js:1392:3
    at /opt/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:339:34
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/opt/bundle/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:153:9)
    at /opt/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:158:5
    at /opt/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:388:5
    at Function.run (/opt/bundle/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
    at /opt/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:387:11
```

here is the docker file:

```js
FROM lambdalinux/baseimage-amzn
#RUN yum update -y
RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
RUN yum install -y tar nodejs gcc-c++ make

ADD ./novice-driver.tar.gz /opt/

EXPOSE 8000

ENV ROOT_URL https://novicedriver.com.au
ENV MONGO_URL "mongodb://abc:xyz@cluster0...sDB?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=myDB"
ENV PORT 8000

WORKDIR /opt/bundle/
RUN npm install fibers underscore source-map-support semver

CMD node ./main.js
```

Any suggestions how to approch this issue? Thanks

Comment: 1) Did you run `meteor npm i` _before_ building your bundle? 2) How did you build your bundle? 3) Why don't you do `npm i` inside `/opt/bundle/programs/server/` folder?

Comment: I do not run `meteor npm i`, what does it do? but I do `npm install --production` then `meteor build . --architecture os.linux.x86_64` I could not locate the folder you indicated on my local mac OSX.

Comment: I am also seeing this after upgrading to 1.5.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

In Docker container you should install `npm` modules for your bundle first:

```
# Install node modules
WORKDIR /opt/bundle/programs/server
RUN npm install

WORKDIR /opt/bundle
# do you other stuff
```

Also, before building app bundle (on your local machine or CI server), it's better to use: `meteor npm install --production` rather than just `npm install --production`.

Comment: Yes, this seems new and it was not required in the past. Thanks for pointing out that you have to run `npm install` inside the bundle.